# How to delete one item by AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hey guys I want to delete item by id in an AngularJS function. How can I get id from delete button?

```
<table data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myController">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>School</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Update</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="student in students">
            <td>{{student.id}}</td>
            <td>{{student.name}}</td>
            <td>{{student.school}}</td>
            <td>{{student.gender}}</td>
            <td>{{student.email}}</td>
            <td><a href="#" id="tagaUpdate" >Update</a></td>
            <td><a href="#" id="tagaDelete" data-ng-click="deleteItem({{student.id}})">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller("myController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.deleteItem = function (id) {
        alert(id);//it doesn't show alert here
    };
});
```

I think the problem is here `data-ng-click="deleteItem({{student.id}})"`. But when I check it shows me value `data-ng-click="deleteItem(5)`.

Comment: ramamoorthy_villi's answer will solve your problem. But you are trying to to manipulate DOM from controller. But controllers are not for manipulating DOM, for this purpose you can use directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace

```
<a href="#" id="tagaDelete" data-ng-click="deleteItem({{student.id}})">Delete</a>
```

by

```
<a href="#" id="tagaDelete" data-ng-click="deleteItem(student.id)">Delete</a>
```